# which CSS selector should I use for accessing the numbers on a graph in a website ( python)

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to exatract some numbers from a graph on this page ( https://www.zoopla.co.uk/local-info/?outcode=cm15&incode=9bq )

There are 5 tabs in that graph.

I am interested in the 5th tab (Newspapers).

When I run this piece of code, I get some info about the first tabbed graph.

but soup.find_all('',id='neighbours-newspapers') returns a blank.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

res=requests.get('https://www.zoopla.co.uk/local-info/?outcode=cm15&incode=9bq')
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')

housing = [item.text.replace('\n','').strip() for item in soup.find_all('',id='local-info-neighbours')]
print(housing)

newspapers = [item.text.replace('\n','').strip() for item in soup.find_all('',id='neighbours-newspapers')]
print(newspapers)
```

I am not sure how to access an id within an id if that's what it is. Could someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex and requests

```
import requests
import re
import ast

headers = {
    'Referer' : 'https://www.zoopla.co.uk/',
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'
}
res = requests.get('https://www.zoopla.co.uk/widgets/local-info/neighbours-chart.html?outcode=cm15&incode=9bq&category=Newspapers', headers = headers)
data = re.search(r'categories: (\[.*])', res.text ,flags=re.DOTALL).group(1)
items = re.findall(r'(\[.*])', data)

papers = ast.literal_eval(items[0])
numbers = ast.literal_eval(items[1])
result = list(zip(papers, numbers))
print(result)
```